# How to use YII's createCommand to also return total items?

Tags: yii

Let's say I do a simple query:

```
$products = 
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
  ->select('*')
  ->from('products')
  ->limit(9)
  ->queryAll();
```

Let's say there are 500 products in the database. Is there a way I can get YII to automatically return the total number (count) of products if the "limit" was included? Perhaps return an object like this:

```
$products->products = array( ... products ... )
$products->totalProducts = 500;
```

The problem is, if LIMIT is included, it will return  items, and the count will therefore be 9. I want a solution whereby it will return the 9 items, but also the count of say 200 items if there were 200 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either have to run two queries (a count(*) query without the limit and then the limited query) or you can send you can retrieve your products using [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider) and let it do it for you.  But it generally takes two queries.

**Note:** one of the nifty features in Yii 1.1.13 is that you can send your query builder command in to the `CSqlDataProvider` if you're going to be using a dataprovider.  More information at on [this pull request that fixed it](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/pull/1500). That way, you can both use the power of query builder while also being able to shift your data into a dataprovider.  Previously you had to build your SQL statement manually or grab the queryText of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Why not an easy:

```
$сount = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select count(*) from table')->queryScalar();
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select count(*) from tbl_table')->queryScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **execute()** instead of **query()** because execute returns rows count.
example:

```
$rowCount = $command->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using COUNT like this:

```
$dbCommand = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `products`");
$data = $dbCommand->queryAll();
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT: You might find this useful too: [CDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider)

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select * from tbl_table')->queryAll(); //It's return the Array

echo count($sql); //Now using count() method we can count the array.
```